# Adding a Printer to my Print Server Failing

Tags: networking, printer, network-printer, windows-server-2012

So, on the Windows Server page I read the following.

> Step 4: Add Network Printers Automatically
>
> Print Management (Printmanagement.msc) can automatically detect all
>   the printers that are located on the same subnet as the computer on
>   which you are running Print Management, install the appropriate
>   printer drivers, set up the queues, and share the printers.
>
> To automatically add network printers to a printer server Open the
>   Administrative Tools folder, and then double-click Print Management.
>   In the Printer Management tree, right-click the appropriate server,
>   and then click Add Printer. On the Printer Installation page of the
>   Network Printer Installation Wizard, click Search the network for
>   printers, and then click Next. If prompted, specify which driver to
>   install for the printer.

So, I have got to this point, made sure the printer (Canon MP620) is on and correctly plugged into the network. However, when I click "Search the network for printers", the wizard doesn't find it. Now, I can't get any further. Is there anything I could be doing wrong? How should I proceed moving forwards?

Comment: Add the make/model of your printer. Some printers just don't get found. I have a HP printer that can only be found using HP's software.

Comment: It is a Canon MP620. I have added that to the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I have solved this. I will detail the process I went though to get it working.

First, I reset the printer to factory defaults. I then turned wireless LAN off (because according to an article on the net that can often confuse matters), which instantly resulting in the printer being assigned an IP address by the DHCP server. Success. (Previous to this I also installed the drivers for the printer with no success)

Then, after successfully adding the printer using the automated method in the original question the printer would only "print to file" and wouldn't actually print. So, I checked the printer's ports in it's properties on `Print Management` to find that it's port was set to "Print to file". So I added a new port, used automated search to find the printer and added a new port that way.

The printer now works. Hope that helps anyone in my situation in future.